# SQL Profile giving server not found exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio, profile

I'm trying to use Profiles in my program. Creating the necessary tables using aspnet_regsql.exe from the command line worked fine. However, A System.Web.HttpException  exception is thrown saying it is unable to connect to the database when I try to run the application. This is strange because I am connected to the database on the Server Explorer in VS 2013. Here is the error message on my application's website.

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
>   Specified)

Here's the relevant code in my web config file.

```
<profile defaultProvider="SqlProvider" inherits="[Namespace].AccountProfile">
    <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="SqlProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="[stringname]"/>
    </providers>
    <properties>
        <add name="Rows" type="System.String"/>
        <add name="Area" type="System.String"/>
    </properties>
</profile>
```

And here is the code in my application where the exception is thrown

AccountProfile.cs

```
public class AccountProfile : ProfileBase
{
      static public AccountProfile CurrentUser
      {
           get { return (AccountProfile)(ProfileBase.Create(Membership.GetUser().UserName)); }
      }

    ....
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the Membership.GetUser() part of the code was still trying to use the LocalSqlServer connection string found in the machine.config file instead of the database connection string I provided in the web.config. Adding `<clear />` in my connectionString configuration helped me figure this out.

```
<connectionStrings>
<clear />
    <add name="..." connectionString="Data Source=...;Initial Catalog=...;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```